# Link error with qpid-proton-0.17.0

Tags: amqp, qpid

When I build my qpid-proton-0.17.0 program I get this link error:

```
undefined reference to proton::event_loop::inject(std::function<void ()>)
```

Here is how I build:

```
g++ -std=c++14 myprog.cpp -o myprog -lqpid-proton-cpp -lboost_system -lcrypto -lssl
```

Am I missing a library?

Also, without -std=c++14 or -std=c++11 the link issue goes away. But I will need -std=c++11 at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rebuilt qpid-proton-0.17.0 libraries with -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11 and that fixed my issue.