# "Undefined reference to" Linking errors when trying to build with headers (QPID/Proton C++)

Tags: c++, amqp, qpid

I'm a C++ neophyte and I am totally in over my head, but I'm trying anyway!

**EDIT:** here is a simple code repo reproducer that generates the error mentioned: https://github.com/thoraxe/qpid-proton-test

http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.33.0/proton/cpp/examples/simple_recv.cpp.html

I am trying to incorporate the above into an [existing project](https://github.com/redhat-gamedev/srt-game-server/tree/proton-client) and struggling badly. In order to be able to use various instances of the QPID Proton sender/receiver, I need to include their class files. The example is a pure cpp and includes no header file.

In order to include a receiver (consumer) class, I need to write a header file. And it's all falling apart on compile.

Here's a really simple example. I'm trying to start out and just go more or less line by line with the receiver example. So, here's my cpp:

```c++
#include "ProtonConsumer.h"
```

Here's the header:

```c++
class ProtonConsumer : public proton::messaging_handler {
  private:
    std::string url;
    proton::receiver receiver;

  public:
    // constructor
    ProtonConsumer(const std::string &s) : url(s) {};

};
```

In my main, I'm trying to simply use an instance of the `ProtonConsumer`:

```c++
#include "ProtonConsumer.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
    std::string     strProtonURI = "127.0.0.1/COMMAND.IN";
    std::cout << "Hello, world!\n";
    ProtonConsumer pProtonConsumer(strProtonURI);
}
```

When I try to build (cmake), I get all kinds of "undefined reference to" and other errors:

```
[main] Building folder: qpid-proton-test 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/bin/cmake --build /home/thoraxe/Red_Hat/openshift/qpid-proton-test/build --config Debug --target all -- -j 10
[build] Scanning dependencies of target qpid-proton-test
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] [100%] Linking CXX executable qpid-proton-test
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `proton::endpoint::endpoint()':
[build] /usr/include/proton/endpoint.hpp:67: undefined reference to `vtable for proton::endpoint'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `proton::link::link()':
[build] /usr/include/proton/link.hpp:49: undefined reference to `vtable for proton::link'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `proton::receiver::receiver()':
[build] /usr/include/proton/receiver.hpp:48: undefined reference to `vtable for proton::receiver'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `ProtonConsumer::ProtonConsumer(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
[build] /home/thoraxe/Red_Hat/openshift/qpid-proton-test/ProtonConsumer.h:26: undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::messaging_handler()'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: /home/thoraxe/Red_Hat/openshift/qpid-proton-test/ProtonConsumer.h:26: undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::~messaging_handler()'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `proton::internal::pn_ptr<pn_link_t>::pn_ptr(pn_link_t*)':
[build] /usr/include/proton/internal/object.hpp:48: undefined reference to `proton::internal::pn_ptr_base::incref(void*)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `proton::internal::pn_ptr<pn_link_t>::~pn_ptr()':
[build] /usr/include/proton/internal/object.hpp:55: undefined reference to `proton::internal::pn_ptr_base::decref(void*)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `proton::internal::pn_ptr<pn_link_t>::pn_ptr(proton::internal::pn_ptr<pn_link_t> const&)':
[build] /usr/include/proton/internal/object.hpp:49: undefined reference to `proton::internal::pn_ptr_base::incref(void*)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x20): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_container_start(proton::container&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x28): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_container_stop(proton::container&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x30): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_message(proton::delivery&, proton::message&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x38): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_sendable(proton::sender&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x40): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_transport_open(proton::transport&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x48): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_transport_close(proton::transport&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x50): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_transport_error(proton::transport&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x58): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_connection_open(proton::connection&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x60): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_connection_close(proton::connection&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x68): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_connection_error(proton::connection&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x70): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_session_open(proton::session&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x78): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_session_close(proton::session&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x80): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_session_error(proton::session&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x88): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_receiver_open(proton::receiver&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x90): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_receiver_detach(proton::receiver&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x98): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_receiver_close(proton::receiver&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xa0): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_receiver_error(proton::receiver&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xa8): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_sender_open(proton::sender&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xb0): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_sender_detach(proton::sender&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xb8): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_sender_close(proton::sender&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xc0): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_sender_error(proton::sender&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xc8): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_tracker_accept(proton::tracker&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xd0): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_tracker_reject(proton::tracker&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xd8): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_tracker_release(proton::tracker&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xe0): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_tracker_settle(proton::tracker&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xe8): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_delivery_settle(proton::delivery&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xf0): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_sender_drain_start(proton::sender&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0xf8): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_receiver_drain_finish(proton::receiver&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x100): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_connection_wake(proton::connection&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV14ProtonConsumer[_ZTV14ProtonConsumer]+0x108): undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::on_error(proton::error_condition const&)'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `ProtonConsumer::~ProtonConsumer()':
[build] /home/thoraxe/Red_Hat/openshift/qpid-proton-test/ProtonConsumer.h:19: undefined reference to `proton::receiver::~receiver()'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: /home/thoraxe/Red_Hat/openshift/qpid-proton-test/ProtonConsumer.h:19: undefined reference to `proton::messaging_handler::~messaging_handler()'
[build] /usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI14ProtonConsumer[_ZTI14ProtonConsumer]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for proton::messaging_handler'
[build] collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[build] gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/build.make:103: qpid-proton-test] Error 1
[build] gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:636: CMakeFiles/qpid-proton-test.dir/all] Error 2
[build] gmake: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code
```

I have dug around in GitHub and found various other examples where headers are used, [for example here](https://github.com/Pryancito/zeusircd/blob/7d9bb9f2752395256d0cc096a4d5555bd05a4973/include/amqp.h). Many of the undefined reference errors I'm getting in my code are functions declared in the header file of this reference example. I believe that the `~ProtonConsumer` error is related to having a destructor, or something?

I'm super totally lost and not quite sure where to go from here. It looks like I might have to define all of the `_ZTV14ProtonConsumer` undefined references in my header and my class, but I'm not sure about the other things. The code example I referenced did not declare all of the functions. It's not entirely clear from the [messaging handler documentation](http://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.33.0/proton/cpp/api/classproton_1_1messaging__handler.html) which functions might be required to be declared, or not.

After considerable digging, the only thing I found that might be related was [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44030140/link-error-with-qpid-proton-0-17-0), but it doesn't seem related after inspection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A: What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400) You seem to be not linking the result of compiling that cpp file you said you were using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not linking with the Proton library. Use [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) to locate the library you're trying to use, and then [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) to link with it.

For example, `find_package(ProtonCpp REQUIRED)`.

Comment: Thanks - this was the fix. I guess the question is why the existing activemq-ccp library worked without `find_package`. I'll have to read up on the difference!

Comment: My guess, because something was pulling it in already. What's the compile and link commands, btw, wnen you use activemq-cpp without find_package? Does it include `-lactivemq_cpp` or a similar gcc switch? If you use CMake with make, you can get the compiler commandlines by running `make clean; VERBOSE=1 make`.